# Fourier transform of log(t)*exp(-t^2)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ be the function defined by
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} \log(x) \exp(-x^2) &\text{if $x\geq 0$}\\
0 &\text{if $x<0$.} \end{cases}$$

What is the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}(t)$ of $f$? I don't expect there to be a closed form; all I need is a convenient, rapidly converging approximation so that I can estimate the maximum of $|t^2\cdot \widehat{f}(t)|$ and the like, say.

Answer (score 1):

We may compute the Fourier transform of $g(x)=\log(x)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{x>0}$ as the following limit:

$$ \widehat{g}(\xi)=\lim_{\lambda\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(x)e^{-i\xi x}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\frac{i\gamma}{\xi}-\frac{\pi}{2|\xi|}+\frac{i}{\xi}\log(|\xi|)\tag{1}$$
then compute the Fourier transform of $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$:
$$ \widehat{h}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{-i\xi x}\,dx =\sqrt{\pi}\,e^{-\xi^2/4}\tag{2} $$
then approximate the convolution between the RHS of $(1)$ and the RHS of $(2)$, that gives $\widehat{g\cdot h}$.